# Is it possible to use HTTP/3 with NGINX-Node.js combination already?

Tags: nginx, node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, quic, http3

NGINX supports HTTP/3 [since 1.25.0](https://nginx.org/en/docs/quic.html). Node.js currently does not support HTTP/3 or QUIC out-of-the-box but it seems there are some C++ addons implementations, like [FAILS'](https://github.com/fails-components/webtransport).

HTTP/3 (more specifically, WebTransport) provides some very interesting features, including support for non-ordered streams ([`WebTransport.datagrams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebTransport/datagrams)).

I'm interested, could I use these features (e.g. create a WebTransport server) in Node.js, which receives requests from NGINX reverse proxy? I think currently NGINX is able to talk to proxy [only via](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) HTTP 1.0 or 1.1.

Maybe there is some kind of indirect approach or maybe some third-party module for NGINX that allows this?

Comment: reverse proxy nginx does only http 1.1 as you already know. http3 will be used till the nginx and it traverse the request into http 1.1 compliant conform one into the backend. the only way I see here is just either if it's a native site use root for it or use a port forwarding to direct access to the application without nginx, but I am unsure if this is the wanted behavior

Comment: Is there an approach that doesn't require circumventing NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

Nightly builds of uWebSockets.js now ship with experimental HTTP/3 support*.
`npm install uNetworking/uWebSockets.js#binaries`

See here for more information

https://unetworkingab.medium.com/h3-meet-node-js-1d952e9bdd74

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question how to do this _without circumventing_ NGINX. The fact that it is possible to use HTTP/3 in Node (indirectly) is already presented in the question.